# Expresión regular para valores consecutivos en una contraseña

Tags: javascript, regex, regular

necesito ayuda con un problema que tengo, necesito que valide que no haya valores consecutivos; a lo que me refiero es que no se pueda poner:

123 ó abc ó 345 ó cdf. etc

Actualmente tengo esta expresión regular:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$#@&*_+-])(?!.*(.)\1{2})[a-zA-Z0-9$#@&*_+-]{8,15}$
```

La cual valida lo siguiente: si tiene mayúsculas, una minúsculas, si tiene un numero, si tiene los caracteres especiales y que un carácter idéntico no sea repetido más de 3 veces, con una longitud mínima de 8 y máxima de 15

**Ejemplo:**

HsEsp3$6_* --Valido

HsEsp3$666_* --invalido

Lo único que me hace falta es validar el que no haya valores consecutivos, ¿¿¿se puede hacer con una expresión regular o se tiene que hacer de otra manera???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opción sin usar expresiones regulares. El funcionamiento es simple: compara el valor del caracter actual vs el anterior y verifica si tienen una diferencia de 1. Si es así es porque son consecutivos.

La función, además tiene de forma variable la cantidad de caracteres que quieres que no se repitan `consec`, y puse otro argumento `reverse` si quieres desactivar la evaluación de forma inversa (654...).

```js
function validate(string, consec=3, reverse=true) {
    let cpos = cneg = cequ = 1;
    let last_code = cur_code = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
        cur_code = string[i].charCodeAt(0);
        if(cur_code-last_code == 1) { 
            cpos++; // consecutivos
        } else if (reverse && (cur_code-last_code == -1)) { 
            cneg++; // consecutivos en reversa
        } else if (cur_code == last_code) {
            cequ++; // iguales
        } else { 
            cpos = cneg = cequ = 1;
        }
        //
        if([cpos, cneg, cequ].includes(consec)) {
            return false;
        }
        last_code = cur_code;
    }
    return true;
}

// Pruebas
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$6_*')); // true
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$666_*')); // false
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$ABC_*')); // false
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$379_*')); // true
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$678_*', 4)); // true (tolera hasta 3 consecutivos)
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$678_*', 3)); // false
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$6543')); // false (reverse activado)
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$6543', 3, false)); // true (reverse desactivado)
console.log(validate('HsEsp3$?@A_*')); // false ** ¡¿qué?!
```

Si observas el último caso "falla", esto es porque `?` `@` y `A` son [caracteres consecutivos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters). Tendrías que modificar el código para que si el caracter actual no es una letra o número no haga las comparaciones, pero si no te importa, lo dejas así.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto me ayudo muchisimo más

Answer (score 1):

No creo que con expresiones regulares sea posible hallar si posee caracteres consecutivos, pero con un poco de código y un bucle `for` si es posible, aquí te dejo mi solución:

```js
let pass1 = "Hxj_6128B"; // válido
let pass2 = "Hxj_1234B"; // no válido

console.log( !hasConsecutive(pass1) );
console.log( !hasConsecutive(pass2) );


// si en alguna parte tiene 3 (o más) caracteres y números consecutivos retorna true, si no, false.
function hasConsecutive (input) {
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  
  let list = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
  let coincidences = 0;
  
  for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    let lastChar = input.charAt(i - 1);
    let char = input.charAt(i);
    let expectedChar = list.charAt(list.indexOf(lastChar) + 1);
   
    if (char == expectedChar) coincidences += coincidences ? 1 : 2;
    else coincidences = 0;
    
    // si son 3 caracteres consecutivos
    if (coincidences == 3) return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

Espero que te sirva, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy acertado todo

Answer (score 0):

No creo que sea buena idea una expresión regular entera, porque sería muy enredado.

¿Por qué no mejor verificas cada una de esas reglas en la cadena de forma consecutiva?

No sé como sería en javascript, pero algo como:

```
regex.match("[A-Z]", passw) # que tenga mayusculas
regex.match("[a-z]", passw) # que tenga minusculas
regex.match("\d", passw) # que tenga al menos un digito
regex.match("[$%&_-]", passw) # que tenga caracteres especiales
regex.match("^(.){8,15}$", passw) # que tenga una longitud de entre [8,15]
regex.match("(.)\1{2,}", passw) # busca los caracteres que se repitan más de 3 veces
```

En `(.)\1{2,}`, si la condición se cumple, entonces mandas una excepción con la validación de la contraseña.

De esta manera, cada condición la puedes poner dentro de una serie de validadores que regresan cada caso que NO se cumpla en la contraseña. Por ejemplo:

```
if not regex.match("(.)\1{2,}", passw):
    raise PasswdError("Los caracteres no se pueden repetir mas de 3 veces")
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la siguiente expresión regular, en la cual verifica si existe caracteres repetidos continuos en el texto que ingresas.

```
^(?!.*(.)\1)
```

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
const regex = /^(?!.*(.)\1)/,
  t = document.getElementById('t'),
  r = document.getElementById('r');

t.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (regex.test(t.value)) {
    r.innerText = 'Es válido';
  } else {
    r.innerText = 'Es inválido'; 
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="t" type="text" />
<div id="r"></div>
```